# Binding CarouselPage content pages to view model

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am trying to use a CarouselPage in Xamarin Forms.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TestForms.Views;assembly=TestForms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="TestForms.Views.Photos" ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}">
    <CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ContentPage >
          <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="50">
            <Label Text="ContentPage"></Label>
            <Label Text="{Binding Title}"></Label>
            <Label Text="{Binding Description}"></Label>
          </StackLayout>
          </ContentPage>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselPage>
```

In the view model I have

```
List<ContentPage> ContentPages = new List<ContentPage>();
foreach (var photo in Photos)
{
    var page = new ContentPage();
    page.BindingContext = new PhotoDetailViewModel(photo);
    ContentPages.Add(page);
 }
Pages = new ObservableCollection<ContentPage>(ContentPages);
```

When I render this, I get a list of pages for all the photos. but I can't seem to bind the title or description in the individual page. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: CarouselPage doesn't work with children ContentPage, it works with children ContentView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your `CarouselPage` wired up correctly

Just need to change your view model slightly.

I'm assuming your `Title` and `Description` Properties are in your `PhotoDetailViewModel`?

if so the binding you are creating in your `CarouselPage` is not working because it is binded to the List of `ContentPage`, which wouldn't have the properties "Title" and "Description"

in your `CarouselPage` your have already set up an `ItemsSource` binding which should automatically set the `BindingContext` of your child pages in your `CarouselPage`. So you dont need to do it manually.

So instead create an `ObservableCollection` of `PhotoDetailViewModel` in your ViewModel and bind the `ItemsSource` of your `CarouselPage` to that.

So Remove:

```
List<ContentPage> ContentPages = new List<ContentPage>();
foreach (var photo in Photos)
{
    var page = new ContentPage();
    page.BindingContext = new PhotoDetailViewModel(photo);
    ContentPages.Add(page);
 }
Pages = new ObservableCollection<ContentPage>(ContentPages);
```

And add:

```
Pages = new ObservableCollection<PhotoDetailViewModel>(Photos.Select(p => new PhotoDetailViewModel(p));
```

Make sure to change the Property Type of `Pages` to `ObservableCollection<PhotoDetailViewModel>`

And that should be all you need to change

Answer (score 0):

As I said you should use ContentView instead of ContentPage. Below is working example

```
public partial class AnotherCarouselPage : ContentPage
{
    public class Zoo
    {
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Zoo> Zoos { get; set; }

    public AnotherCarouselPage()
    {
        Zoos = new ObservableCollection<Zoo>
    {
        new Zoo
        {
            ImageUrl = "http://content.screencast.com/users/JamesMontemagno/folders/Jing/media/23c1dd13-333a-459e-9e23-c3784e7cb434/2016-06-02_1049.png",
            Name = "Woodland Park Zoo"
        },
        new Zoo
        {
            ImageUrl =    "http://content.screencast.com/users/JamesMontemagno/folders/Jing/media/6b60d27e-c1ec-4fe6-bebe-7386d545bb62/2016-06-02_1051.png",
            Name = "Cleveland Zoo"
            },
        new Zoo
        {
            ImageUrl = "http://content.screencast.com/users/JamesMontemagno/folders/Jing/media/e8179889-8189-4acb-bac5-812611199a03/2016-06-02_1053.png",
            Name = "Phoenix Zoo"
        }
    };

        InitializeComponent();

        carousel.ItemsSource = Zoos;
        carousel.PositionSelected += Carousel_PositionSelected;
        carousel.ItemSelected += Carousel_ItemSelected;
    }

    private void Carousel_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Carousel_PositionSelected(object sender, SelectedPositionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

page xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
             x:Class="ButtonRendererDemo.AnotherCarouselPage"
             x:Name="devicePage"
    BackgroundColor="Gray">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <control:CarouselView x:Name="carousel" >
        <control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
              <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
              <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </DataTemplate>
        </control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
      </control:CarouselView>
    </StackLayout>

  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```